# How to convert .mov videos to iPhone playable mp4 videos

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert .mov videos to mp4(should be playable in iPhone) using **ffmpeg**.I am using Linux CLI. I have tried the following command:

```
-i source.MOV -s qvga -b 384k -vcodec libx264 -r 23.976 -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -vpre baseline -crf 22 -deinterlace -o output.mp4
```

I get the output

```
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-o'
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, what have you tried that didn't work, are you writing a program to do this or just trying to it manually?

Comment: @jrtuton   ,I just tried to execute this command  ffmpeg -i source.MOV -s qvga -b 384k -vcodec libx264 -r 23.976 -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -vpre baseline -crf 22 -deinterlace -o output.mp4       I got the error  
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-o'

Comment: I don't think this is a question for SO, it is a support question for ffmpeg.

Comment: @jrturton: That, or SuperUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of tasks, I switched from FFmpeg to [HandBrakeCLI](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide#presets):

```
HandBrakeCLI -i source.mov -o destination.mp4 --preset='iPhone & iPod Touch'
```

Comment: I think HandBrakeCLI is windows tool ,I need it in linux

Comment: HandBrakeCLI runs on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux, check its [download page](http://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php).

Comment: I've used this command in CLI ,its working ,but converted videos playing only seconds when the original video have long way to go

Answer (score 3):

There is no `-o` to output a file. Just remove it and pass the desired output filename as the last argument.

Comment: Can you give me some working commands ,cause we don't have an iPhone,if I could convert it  ,but can't play .I really wanna convert .mov ,.wmv to mp4

Comment: Your answer actually solves the problem, the above answer just proposes alternate.